# Iframe inside link to a website that is embedded on

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe from site1.com embedded on a website site2.com and in that iframe I have a link to /page.html
When I click on that link it takes me to the page of where the iframe comes from site1.com/page.html and I want to take me to a link on the current site site2.com/page.html.
I this possible, maybe with JavaScript?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the [`base`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element within your iframe.

```html
<base href="http://site1.com">
<a href="/page.html">Link</a>
```

The hostname of the parent window can be accessed by `document.referrer`, which can be injected to the DOM with JavaScript like this:

```js
var baseElement = document.createElement('base');
baseElement.setAttribute('href', document.referrer);
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(baseElement);
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working. I would like the base to be the current host, the current website that the iframe is embedded on. I tried window.location.host but it doesn't work or there is something that I'm not doing right.

Comment: is your question resolved or you want to get the hostname of the root website with JavaScript to make it dynamic?

Comment: check the update if you want it non hard-coded

Comment: It is resolved just what I needed. What do you mean when you say to make it dynamic?